# Address Sanitizer can not detect memory leaks with option -O

Tags: c++, c, memory-leaks, address-sanitizer

When I use Address Sanitizer（clang v3.4） to detect memory leak, I found that using -O(except -O0) option would always lead to a no-leak-detected result.

The code is simple:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int* array = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 100);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) //Initialize
    array[i] = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

when compile with -O0,

```
clang -fsanitize=address -g -O0 main.cpp
```

it will detect memory correctly,

```
==2978==WARNING: Trying to symbolize code, but external symbolizer is not initialized!

=================================================================
==2978==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 400 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x4652f9 (/home/mrkikokiko/sdk/MemoryCheck/a.out+0x4652f9)
    #1 0x47b612 (/home/mrkikokiko/sdk/MemoryCheck/a.out+0x47b612)
    #2 0x7fce3603af44 (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21f44)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 400 byte(s) leaked in 1 allocation(s).
```

however, when -O added,

```
clang -fsanitize=address -g -O main.cpp
```

nothing is detected! And I find nothing about it in official document.

Comment: Your code is C code, not C++ code. The C++ tag is wrong, and a C tag should be used.

Comment: You are not using array, maybe it gets optimized out?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch see the line `clang -fsanitize=address -g -O main.cpp` - that indicates OP is using C++  (the clang compiler selects language based on the file extension `.cpp`). OP's code is valid C++.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because [your code is completely optimized away](https://godbolt.org/g/X05Y9g). The resulting assembly is something like:

```
main:                                   # @main
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    retq
```

Without any call to `malloc`, there is no memory allocation... and therefore no memory leak.

---

In order to to have *AddressSanitizer* detect the memory leak, you can either:

- [Compile with optimizations disabled](https://godbolt.org/g/0ul4bk), as [Simon Kraemer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4181011/simon-kraemer) mentioned in the comments.
- Mark `array` as `volatile`, [preventing the optimization](https://godbolt.org/g/U8wvYo):

  ```
   main:                                   # @main
          pushq   %rax
          movl    $400, %edi              # imm = 0x190
          callq   malloc                  # <<<<<< call to malloc
          movl    $9, %ecx
  .LBB0_1:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
          movl    $0, -36(%rax,%rcx,4)
          movl    $0, -32(%rax,%rcx,4)
          movl    $0, -28(%rax,%rcx,4)
          movl    $0, -24(%rax,%rcx,4)
          movl    $0, -20(%rax,%rcx,4)
          movl    $0, -16(%rax,%rcx,4)
          movl    $0, -12(%rax,%rcx,4)
          movl    $0, -8(%rax,%rcx,4)
          movl    $0, -4(%rax,%rcx,4)
          movl    $0, (%rax,%rcx,4)
          addq    $10, %rcx
          cmpq    $109, %rcx
          jne     .LBB0_1
          xorl    %eax, %eax
          popq    %rcx
          retq
  ```

Comment: @SimonKraemer: I assumed the OP was aware of this as he mentioned that when compiling with `-O0` the memory leak is reported correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Look into the generated code.

Both GCC & Clang actually know about the semantics of `malloc`. Because on my Linux/Debian system `<stdlib.h>`  contains

```
extern void *malloc (size_t __size) __THROW __attribute_malloc__ __wur;
```

and the `__attribute_malloc__` & `_wur` (and `__THROW`) are macros defined elsewhere. Read about [Common Function Attributes](http://ttps://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html) in [GCC documentation](http://ttps://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/), and Clang documentation [says](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html):

> Clang aims to support a broad range of GCC extensions.

I strongly suspect that with `-O`  the call to `malloc` is *optimized* by removing it.

On my Linux/x86-64 machine using `clang -O -S psbshdk.c` (with clang 3.8) I am indeed getting:

```
    .globl  main
    .align  16, 0x90
    .type   main,@function
 main:                                   # @main
    .cfi_startproc
 # BB#0:
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    retq
 .Lfunc_end0:
    .size   main, .Lfunc_end0-main
    .cfi_endproc
```

The address sanitizer is working on the emitted binary (which won't contain any `malloc` call).

BTW, you could compile with `clang -O -g` then use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), or compile with `clang -O -fsanitize=address -g`. Both `clang` & `gcc` are able to optimize and give some debug information (which might be "approximate" when optimizing a lot).